# get the thrustvector of a drone in cartesian coordinates

Tags: java, coordinates

So we have to program a drone and we have the pitch,yaw and roll (in degrees) given and howmuch thrust we have.
I'm trying to calculate the thrustvector which has a norm (which is howmuch thrust the drone has, which we know)
so this vector:
[thrust vector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9btC.jpg)

Our drone's pitch yaw roll is defined as so:
[pitch yaw roll drone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZG08.png)

I do know how to calculate the directional vector
like this:

```
x = cos(yaw)*cos(pitch)
y = sin(yaw)*cos(pitch)
z = sin(pitch)
```

I forgot that this points out of the camera of the drone (the front of the drone), and I need to get the vector perpendicular to the top of the drone (the center of it).
How do I do this?

Comment: Perpendicular to its center? How would you define a vector as being perpendicular to a point?

Comment: In which cartesian coordinate system? The global one underlying the WGS 84, meaning the x axis goes through the equator at the longitude of London? Or one relative to the drone itself?

Comment: @yeoman I mean to the center of the top plane of the drone (so on the center of mass)
Also the coordinate system relative to the drone itself, so the y-axis (the one pointing up) is extended in the gravity vector

Comment: Traditionally, the z axis points up :) What if the drone pitches or rolls? Does the coordinate system tilt then, too? Does it follow its yawning, so the x axis always looks forward?

Comment: I always type yawn instead of yaw :D